# Upgrade to imageresizer 4.1.9 loses my license

Tags: imageresizer

I've just upgraded from imageresizer 4.0.5 to 4.1.9 .  I had a license for the 4.0.5 product, but when i upgraded via nuget, I'm now getting the red dot and /resizer.debug.ashx tells me that no licenses are found.

If i go to my original order quote, i see that i have an ImageResizer v4 Elite License [deprecated], which is news to me that it's deprecated.  Does that mean that, even though i have a v4 license, i don't have access to new v4 updates without purchasing a new license?  If that's not the case, then what is the proper upgrade path for me to be taking?  Looking at https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys , it has mention of a license key in the web.config, which I have never used before and never needed.  I'm not even sure where my license key would be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched from using DRM-free binaries (accessible via your order confirmation email link and MyGet) to binaries from nuget.org.

You need to either use the DRM-free versions or get a free enterprise-wide key to license nuget.org: https://imageresizing.net/licenses/convert

Comment: All right, i've gone to your convert page and switched to the new license type, but i can't find anywhere in my invoice or on the imazen page where my license is.  I see something that says 'license ID', but if i try to use that, i get a error: Failed to parse license (from configuration):
   System.ArgumentException: Not enough ':' delimited segments in license key; failed to deserialize

Comment: It's in the email entitled "Imazen Store License Delivery". I confirmed it was sent - make sure it didn't land in the wrong folder.