# License issues with 4.1.9 (possible non-DRM in MyGet)

Tags: imageresizer

I attempted to update to version 4.1.9, but the binaries did not appear to be DRM-free according to the diagnostics page.

I would be appreciated if anyone could verify that the 4.1.9 binaries in the MyGet repository are DRM-free.

Another user experienced something similar here: [Upgrade to imageresizer 4.1.9 loses my license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148353/upgrade-to-imageresizer-4-1-9-loses-my-license).
I did all the steps in “Troubleshooting a DRM-free installation” without luck. I got the same binaries on my computer and on the build-server.

I downgraded to version 4.1.8 and started experiencing issues that I think is fixed in 4.1.9, so I would prefer to get this working.

Here’s a stack trace of the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at ImageResizer.Configuration.Performance.CircularTimeBuffer.<>c.<DequeueValues>b__14_0(TimeSlotResult r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at ImageResizer.Configuration.Performance.PerIntervalSampling.FireCallbackEvents()
   at ImageResizer.Configuration.Performance.PerIntervalSampling.Record(Int64 timestamp, Int64 count)
   at ImageResizer.Configuration.Performance.MultiIntervalStats.Record(Int64 timestamp, Int64 count)
   at ImageResizer.Configuration.Performance.GlobalPerf.JobComplete(ImageBuilder builder, ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<HandleRequest>b__1(Stream stream)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<TryWriteFile>b__0()
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, HttpModuleRequestAssistant ra, IVirtualFile vf)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The following is an excerpt from the diagnostics page:

```
Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.1.8 2a9f6322 at localhost generated 8/28/2017 1:58:01 PM
Please remember to provide this page when contacting support.

---------------------- Licensing OFF -----------------------

You are using a DRM-disabled version of ImageResizer. License enforcement is OFF.
DRM-enabled assemblies (if present) would see <licenses licenseError='Watermark'>

Need to change domains? Get a discounted upgrade to a floating license: https://imageresizing.net/licenses/convert


---------------------- Licensing OFF -----------------------

You are using ImageResizer Performance Edition plugins.

0 issues detected:


Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="FastScaling" />
<add name="RemoteReader" />
<add name="EPiServerBlobReaderPlugin" />
<add name="EPiFocalPointPlugin" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
<diskcache dir="~/App_Data/ImageCache" />
<remotereader allowAllSignedRequests="true" signingKey="[redacted]" />
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
</resizer>


Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.LicenseDisplay
ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling.FastScalingPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader.RemoteReaderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.EPiServerBlobReader.EPiServerBlobReaderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.EPiFocalPoint.EPiFocalPointPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]

Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, f.sharpen, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True
```

Comment: NuGet has a bug that swaps out NuGet.org and MyGet.org binaries in the machine-wide cache. This is most likely the root of your problem. We've introduced enterprise-wide license keys to resolve this (the alternative is not using NuGet). See https:/imageresizing.net/licenses/convert

Comment: Thanks for the input. The strange thing is that it works with 4.1.8.
I did the steps to clear the machine-wide cache, so not sure it's that. Will consider the licence-key solution.

Comment: 4.1.8 had a bad, bad bug. 4.1.8 and 4.1.9 differ only by a [few lines of code](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/compare/v4.1.8...v4.1.9) - none of which would change how licensing works. 

What version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: NuGet is version 3.5.0.1938.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved by retrieving and adding the license to Web.config and not relying on the DRM-free binaries.